# Android real-time Google Maps location tracking

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, location, real-time

I am working on an Android app where players battle each on their phones in real-time based on their location. On Google maps, you can see where you are, in what direction you are facing, and where you are moving, all from a little blue dot. My question is: How can I integrate something like that in my app, so when the player moves, you can see it on the Google Maps fragment?

**Edit:** Currently, my application drops a new pin every time your location updates. I'm looking for something that ***moves*** the pin rather then adding a new one.

Comment: @halfer Yes, what I'm doing right now is re-centering the map every time the user's lat/long changes. What I need is something that doesn't just represent the camera, but represents the user.

Comment: I will try not to! For newbies, I agree Stack Overflow is rather different - people correct spellings/case in other people's posts, trim and change them - but it is actually intended to be helpful, and makes them more readable, succinct or whatever other improvement. We try to discourage voting commentary in posts and sigs/thanks - they are longstanding editing/writing guidelines and you're not being singled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a temporary solution! What I'm doing now is calling `map.clear()`, and then adding new markers to the places I need... I decided this was best because I am dynamically creating new ones, and not just working with an array, or single marker.

Comment: I tried doing something similar but haven't succeeded in getting desirable results... can you please show me your code?

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42252017/6144372 I have posted the question related to it.

Comment: how you did this, bro? I'm unable to do. Please guide me through!